# Like JBOSS loads login-config.xml file?

Tags: jboss

Was considering an application, to try to improve the response time. When I came across the following excerpt from the file "jboss-4.2.3.GA \ server \ default \ conf \ login-config.xml"

```
<application-policy name="domainroles">
        <authentication>
            <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName">java:jdbc/PostgreAPP</module-option>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery">select "TX_PASS" from appbd."TB_SYSTEM" where "NM_SYSTEM"=?</module-option>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery">select "NM_TRANSACTION" || "CD_OPTION", 'Roles' from appbd."TB_TRANSATION" where "ID_TR" in (select "ID_TR" from appbd."TB_TR_SYSTEM" where "ID_SYSTEM" in (select "ID_SYSTEM" from appbd."TB_SYSTEM" where "NM_SYSTEM" = ?))</module-option>
       </login-module>
   </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

My question is, each incoming request the webservice when the JBOSS will check if the user can access that particular service, it does a select on the database or it already carries all while starting the server?

If I change the SELECT by a properties file will have a significant improvement in performance?

Note: The application receives 5000 requests per minute.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `JaasSecurityManagerService` **caches** authentication results to avoid constant access of the security store associated with login modules. The default **cache** policy is a time based policy that is controlled by the `DefaultCacheTimeout` attribute.

```
<!-- JAAS security manager and realm mapping -->
<mbean code="org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManagerService"
  name="jboss.security:service=JaasSecurityManager">
  <attribute name="SecurityManagerClassName">org.jboss.security.plugins.JaasSecurityManager</attribute>
  <attribute name="DefaultUnauthenticatedPrincipal">anonymous</attribute>
  <!-- DefaultCacheTimeout: Specifies the default timed cache policy timeout
  in seconds.
  If you want to disable caching of security credentials, set this to 0 to
  force authentication to occur every time. This has no affect if the
  AuthenticationCacheJndiName has been changed from the default value.
  -->
  <attribute name="DefaultCacheTimeout">1800</attribute>
  <!-- DefaultCacheResolution: Specifies the default timed cache policy
  resolution in seconds. This controls the interval at which the cache
  current timestamp is updated and should be less than the DefaultCacheTimeout
  in order for the timeout to be meaningful. This has no affect if the
  AuthenticationCacheJndiName has been changed from the default value.
  -->
  <attribute name="DefaultCacheResolution">60</attribute>
</mbean>
```

> **DefaultCacheTimeout:** Specifies the default timed cache policy timeout in seconds. The default value is 1800 seconds (30 minutes).
>   The value you use for the timeout is a tradeoff between frequent
>   authentication operations and how long credential information may be
>   out of sync with respect to the security information store. If you
>   want to disable caching of security credentials, set this to 0 to
>   force authentication to occur every time. This has no affect if the
>   **AuthenticationCacheJndiName** has been changed from the default value.

About change to a properties file, depends on amount of user, roles, filesystem etc.
Also the database will cache  consecutive queries.